# Использование SVG из спрайта в качестве background

Tags: html, css, svg

Моя цель - использовать SVG в повторяющемся background, но мне нужно иметь возможность изменять его цвет заливки в CSS для использования в различных частях веб-сайта.

Насколько я понимаю, если  SVG будет загружен как внешний файл `(background: url (image.svg))`, то тогда я не смогу изменить свойство CSS, например `fill`. С другой стороны, если SVG будет встроен в HTML (`<svg> ... </svg>`), то тогда я не смогу использовать / ссылаться на него в свойстве `background`.

Пожалуйста, поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь, или у вас есть какое-то другое решение для этого?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [using SVG from sprite in a background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66237901/7394871) от участника  [@иkoubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554060/koubin).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66237901/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно маской вырезать фон, благо у `css`-маски такой же синтаксис как и у `background` и всякие `repeat`-ы там прекрасно работают

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
div{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) round;
  animation: colors 3s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes colors{
  0%{background-color: red;}
  50%{background-color: green;}
  100%{background-color: blue;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

А если в блоке какой-то контент, то фон можно сделать псевдой

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.block{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1em;  
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}
.block__content{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.block:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) round;
  animation: colors 3s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes colors{
  0%{background-color: red;}
  50%{background-color: green;}
  100%{background-color: blue;}
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, quae!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрите возможность использования [фильтров CSS](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#interpolation-of-filter-functions) для изменения окраски svg вместо `fill`

В приведенном ниже примере файл svg загружается как внешний файл:

```
background-image:url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg);
```

и его цвет будет изменен при наведении с помощью комбинации фильтров CSS.
Получить желаемую комбинацию фильтров для определенного цвета можно с помощью утилиты:

https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Копируем полученную комбинацию фильтров в CSS

Наведите курсор, чтобы изменить цвет иконок:

```css
.android {
display:inline-block;
width:96px;
height:105px;
background-image:url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg);
}
.android.blue:hover {
 filter: invert(8%) sepia(99%) saturate(7454%) hue-rotate(248deg) brightness(100%) contrast(143%);
} 

.android.red:hover {
 filter: invert(25%) sepia(100%) saturate(7420%) hue-rotate(6deg) brightness(98%) contrast(122%);
} 

.android.gold:hover {
 filter: invert(40%) sepia(31%) saturate(2475%) hue-rotate(1deg) brightness(106%) contrast(103%);
}
```

```html
<div class="android blue">
</div>
<div class="android red">
</div>
<div class="android gold">
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241185/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Comment: очень интересный вариант, но фильтры необходимо изменить, поскольку `.gold` таки зеленый, а его глаз больше не видно

Comment: @highpassion изменил фильтры

Comment: теперь очень хорошо выглядит )